# Values get interchanged while converting from ArrayList to Array android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I have a ArrayList which has some elements. The items in this list are repeated. I want to group the similar values and convert it into an array.

Currently my ArrayList is:-

```
ArrayList<String> isonC = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Value of isonC = `[a, a, a, a, b, c, c,C, c, c, c, d, d, d, d, d, d,d]
I group the so:-

```
icons = isonC.toArray(new String[isonC.size()]);
icons = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(icons)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

I get the values as:-
icons = `[a, c, b,d]`

Whereas the actual order of the elements should be:-

```
[a,b, c,d]
```

Why are the 2nd and 3rd values have interchanged?

Any suggesstions will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Would it suffice to re-order the items (in lexicographical order) after you remove the duplicate elements?

Comment: @JaeHeonLee not really.. I have the given array for the colors whose order need to be the way it is

Comment: You're using a `HashSet`, `HashSet` does not mantain order, the docs say _"It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time"_ (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `TreeSet` instead of HashSet. Try something like below:-

```
TreeSet<String> mySet =  new TreeSet <String>(myArrayList);
myArray =  mySet.toArray(new String[mySet.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) for `LinkedHashSet`:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is the order in which elements were inserted into the set (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if an element is re-inserted into the set. (An element e is reinserted into a set s if s.add(e) is invoked when s.contains(e) would return true immediately prior to the invocation.)

So the following should work, assuming that you want items which appear earlier in `oldArray` to appear earlier in `newArray`:

```
String[] newArray = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(oldArray)).toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: I tried LinkedHashSet but somehow I get the same result except the last two items get swapped

Comment: @user3146095: if I try this with your example input (and the uppercase C changed to a lowercase c), I get the correct order. Are you sure that the ordering in the original ArrayList is correct? Maybe this is a case of "reinsertion" as mentioned in the documentation of the LinkedHashSet